# Xpath in google tool kit with selenium webdriver

Tags: java, gwt, selenium-webdriver

I can not select id,name of xpath in google toolkit.
How to getting id,name of xpath, and using it in selenium webdriver?
Please help me!!
Thank you so much!

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow.  When posting questions, it is best to also post your code to demonstrate a basic knowledge of the topic and your attempts to solve your own problem.

Comment: Also please post the html. It will be very helpful..:)

Comment: <div> 
<input type="text" value="" 
class="GJ5KOJLBM2 GJ5KOJLBD3 GJ5KOJLBA3 GJ5KOJLBCMC" style="width: 83px;"
 id="x-widget-485-input" readonly="" autocomplete="off">
</div>
 id="x-widget-485-input": dynamic.
 I can not  use  id="x-widget-485-input" in selenium webdriver

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem loooong time ago and there's a sample of a potentiel answer.

with the xpath you can also use some other properties to get an element like `class`.

there's an exemple : `By.xpath("/div/input[contains(@class,"GJ5KOJLBM2")]");`

Can you drop a little bit more of your html code ?